# Android ConstraintLayout-2.0.0-alpha4 Fragment doesn't match parent

Tags: android, android-layout

The layout for my `Fragment` is a `ConstraintLayout` with both width and height set to `match_parent`.

Inside it is another `ConstraintLayout` used to make a fixed dimension ratio area.

It works perfectly in `ConstraintLayout-2.0.0-alpha3`, but after I change to alpha4, the outer ConstrainLayout doesn't match parent. It is around 70% original size aligning top-left, I don't know why.

The fragment is attached to a `FrameLayout`, the size of the `FrameLayout` is right.

Here is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".KeyboardFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/game_keyboard_bg"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1.6129"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/corner_tl"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.01"/>

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/corner_br"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.01"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/corner_tl"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/corner_br"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/corner_tl"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/corner_br" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Why another constraint layout is added ?

Comment: Because dimension ratio won't work if parent is not a ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```